# Pass env variable to docker-compose

Tags: python, docker, redis, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have create a sample docker app with python and redis. Python is connected to the redis to store data. I want to pass the `password` `servername` to redis as an environment variable in docker-compose file. How can I achieve that?
Docker-compose:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  nginx_app:
    image: nginx:latest 
    depends_on:
      - flask_app
    volumes:
      - ./default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    ports:
      - 8082:80
    networks:
      - my_project_network
  flask_app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    expose:
      - 5000
    depends_on:
      - redis_app
    networks:
      - my_project_network
  redis_app:
    image: redis:latest
    command: redis-server --requirepass pass123 --appendonly yes
    volumes:
      - ./redis-vol:/data 
    expose:
      - 6379
    networks:
      - my_project_network
networks:
  my_project_network:
```

```
from flask import Flask
from redis import Redis

app = Flask(__name__)
redis = Redis(host='redis_app', port=6379, password='pass123')
@app.route('/')
def hello():
    redis.incr('hits')
    return 'Hello World! I have been seen %s times.' % redis.get('hits')
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", debug=True)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just define environement variables in flask app and do os.getenv of them in python application, than add them to your flask app service in docker compose file:

```
flask_app:
  environment:
    RABBIT_USER: guest
    RABBIT_PASSWORD: pass123
```

In your python file place following:

```
import os

redis = Redis(host='redis_app', port=6379, password=os.getenv('RABBIT_PASSWORD'))
```

Comment: I have added my python file in the question can you tell me where to add os.getenv? Sorry for the silly question I am new to this

Comment: How can give the env variable in redis_app: command: where it say `--requirepass`?

Comment: Set env variable in your shell and pass it with `${PASSWORD}` to get it into your docker-compose

Answer (score 1):

As @AndriyIvaneyko says, in your docker-compose:

```
flask_app:
  environment:
    - PASSWORD=password
```

Another way that you can get this value  is by setting an env variable in your shell `export PASSWORD="password"` and importing it into your docker-compose:

```
flask_app:
  environment:
    - PASSWORD
```

This is the approach I would recommend since it ensures that your credentials are not available in plain text in the docker-compose file. Moreover, collaboration becomes simpler as the env variable can be configured independently.

In your python:

```
from flask import Flask
from redis import Redis
import os

app = Flask(__name__)
redis = Redis(host='redis_app', port=6379, password=os.getenv('PASSWORD'))
@app.route('/')
def hello():
    redis.incr('hits')
    return 'Hello World! I have been seen %s times.' % redis.get('hits')
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", debug=True)
```

You can do the same thing with other env variables. [Here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/) is the documentation.

Comment: it's really full logical duplicate  of my answer man, have you checked existed answers before answering ? 

Comment: @AndriyIvaneyko Updated with alternate method!